# Multiple Paragraph Tags Being Outputted in Jekyll

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid

I can't work out why, but for some reason there are multiple empty paragraph tags being outputted on my page. My template looks like this:

```
<article class="post-item sm-col sm-col-12 md-col md-col-5 {{ thecycle }}">
  <header>
    <h3><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>
  </header>
  <p>{{ post.excerpt }}<p>
  <footer>
    <p class="date"><time pubdate datetime="{{ post.date }}">{{ post.date | date: "%B %-d, %Y" }}</time></p>
  </footer>
</article>
```

But my static HTML looks like this:

[image]

Where are those extra paragraph tags coming from?

Any help with this is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `post.excerpt` is already wrapped in p tag.

If you want to output excerpt with no p tag, you can do `{{ post.excerpt | remove: '<p>' | remove: '</p>' }}`.

[See Jekyll documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#post-excerpts).